# (optidef) A constraint isn't aligned

Tags: optidef

A weird alignment issue:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[short,nocomma]{optidef}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert} % abs

\begin{document}

\begin{mini!}
{ b } { 1 }{}{}
\addConstraint{ \abs{s} \le \sum_{ (i, j) \in \tilde{\gamma}_c } b_{ij} }{ \le \mu \ , \quad }{ \forall c \in \bar{\mathcal{C}}_\text{inner}   }
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns simply aren't wide enough to express the constraint expansively. Thus, do switch to a more compact display form.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[short,nocomma]{optidef}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert} % abs
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\hrule\smallskip\noindent
before:
\begin{mini!}
{ b } { 1}{}{}
\addConstraint%
   { \abs{s} \le \sum_{ (i, j) \in \tilde{\gamma}_c } b_{ij} }
   { \le \mu \ , \quad }
   { \forall c \in \bar{\mathcal{C}}_\text{inner}   }
\end{mini!}

\hrule\smallskip\noindent
after:
\begin{mini!}
{ b } { 1 }{}{}
\addConstraint%
    { \abs{s} \le \sum_{\mathclap{ (i, j) \in \tilde{\gamma}_c }} 
    b_{ij} \le \mu \quad 
    \forall\ c \in \bar{\mathcal{C}}_{\textrm{inner}} }{}{}{}
\end{mini!}

\hrule\smallskip
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does removing the fleqn fix it?

Comment: @ZoharLevi - I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Given that my code example starts with `\documentclass[fleqn,twocolumn]{article}`, how can it be said that I removed the `fleqn` option?

Comment: @ZoharLevi - If you're asking a question about *why* the designer(s) of the `optidef` package made various design choices, I'm sadly in no position to answer your question. I'm not the designer or maintainer of the package, and I have zero knowledge of why, or why not, various design choices were made.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. You said that the column width can't accommodate such an expansive constraint. I assume by expensive you mean long. However, if I remove the fleqn option, then everything (my original code) looks fine. fleqn only aligns the eq to the left, which implies that it's not necessarily a space issue.

Comment: @ZoharLevi - If you're fine with not imposing the `fleqn` document class option, that's naturally fine by me too. (Why wouldn't it be fine, right?!) As you didn't indicate in your query that the `fleqn` option might be ignored, omitting the option was not something that occurred to me as something to be investigated. You also asked, specifically, "*Why* does removing the fleqn fix it?" [emphasis added] As to *why* the creator(s) of the package made certain choices (and/or possibly errors...), I'm simply in no position to address that question.

Comment: I want the fleqn, but I'm just trying to debug the issue. Are you saying that it's not a bug, but intentionally (designer choice) the optidef package decides that if there's an fleqn, then equations are set to be in a longer format, which messes my code?

Comment: @ZoharLevi - You asked me, *why* does omitting a document class option affect the package's behavior in such a major way? I can only repeat myself: I don't know the package's designer, and I have no knowledge of his/her design choices. I'm definitely in no position to answer questions as to *why* he/she made various design choices, and I have no knowledge regarding whether or not they were aware that setting or omitting the `fleqn` option would have a rather large effect. May I suggest you contact the passage's author/maintainer to ask your why-type questions?